# Wpf DataGrid issue

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

To reproduce this issue, Add a user control, paste in the xaml below and then add an instance to a window. Finally set the window's datacontext to an instance of ADummyDataContext (also below)

When you run the application for the first time, you should get a grid with three categories each containing one cat. If you click on either of the bottom two categories and click on a cat name, a blue row will appear showing just the cat's name.

However, if you click the first row and click the cat's row, the blue row will not appear.
**NOTE**: This only happens the first time you run the application. As soon as you click on any other cat the cat in the first category will work as expected.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfUserControls.SimpleGridControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Background="#FFE46400">
<Grid Margin="2,2,2,2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="26" MaxHeight="26" MinHeight="26" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="26" MaxHeight="26" MinHeight="26" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ToolBar Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Content="Button" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" />
        <Button Content="Button" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" />
    </ToolBar>
    <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=KittensView}"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander>
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text=" Items"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Background="LightBlue" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <!-- <Image Height="32" Width="32" Source="/WpfUserControls;component/cat.png"></Image> -->
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height ="20" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="2"></StatusBar>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is the data context class and a Kitten class.

```
    public class ADummyDataContext
{
    public List<Kitten> Kittens { get; set; } 

    public ADummyDataContext()
    {
        Kittens = new List<Kitten>
                      {
                          new Kitten {Color = "Orange", Name = "Alfie", Weight=6, Sex="Male"},
                          new Kitten {Color = "Black and White", Name = "Smudge", Weight = 4, Sex="Female"},
                          new Kitten {Color = "Grey", Name = "Charlotte", Weight = 5, Sex="Female"}
                      };
        KittensView = new ListCollectionView(Kittens);
        KittensView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Weight"));
    }

    public ListCollectionView KittensView { get; set; }
}

public class Kitten
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }

}
```

I would be particularly interested to know how you go about figuring out what the problem is here.

Thanks

Comment: This probably wont fix your problem but in the past I've had trouble when using Lists, maybe try change the list to an ObservableCollection?

Comment: Also a very good point. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the first item in the `DataGrid` is already selected when it's first loaded. However, it isn't really selected, it doesn't appear selected and group isn't expanded. But when you click on the first item for the first time, the `DataGrid` can't tell the difference since `SelectedIndex` was already 0. This is really annoying and I noticed similar behavior several times earlier.

As a workaround, you can unselect the first item in the `Loaded` event of the `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid Loaded="dataGrid1_Loaded"
          ...>
```

*Event handler: Notice that the SelectedIndex is 0*

```
private void dataGrid1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    dataGrid.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Comment: This fixes it for me.  Odd--I wasn't expecting it to, because if I sorted the KittensView differently, I saw the same problem with "Alfie" even though it was last in the grid!

Comment: Curious. It seems odd that that it is only "drawn" or evaluated on a change event. I mean it isn't, it's exactly what I'd expect if this was back in winforms land, but I expected more magic :) Thank you Meleak, happy bonus for the weekend :)

Comment: I think I've made the bounty go to you now, sorry, haven't used them before :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks ! As the Loaded event does not fit my need because Items are loaded through mvvm, I put this workarround in the SelectionChanged event : put my code in a separate answer for more readibility

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Fredrik
here is the code following my comment:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">
```

codebehind.cs:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    dataGrid.SelectionChanged -= DataGrid_SelectionChanged;
    dataGrid.SelectedItem = null;
    dataGrid.SelectionChanged += DataGrid_SelectionChanged;
}
```

this code also allow to refresh data as many as you want