# Button in DataGrid RowDetails requires two cliks, workaround breaks double click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with a button defined in the RowDetailsTemplate. The problem is that when clicking the button, the first click is consumed by the DataGrid to select the row, so you need to click the button twice.

I've tried the workaround offered here: [wpf RowDetailsTemplate focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519593/wpf-rowdetailstemplate-focus):

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="SelectRowDetails"/>
            <Setter Property="DetailsVisibility" Value="{Binding HasCanadet, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    ...
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             ...
             <Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" ... \>
             ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    ...
<DataGrid>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void SelectRowDetails(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var row = sender as DataGridRow;
    if (row == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    row.Focusable = true;
    row.Focus();

    var focusDirection = FocusNavigationDirection.Next;
    var request = new TraversalRequest(focusDirection);
    var elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
    if (elementWithFocus != null)
    {
        elementWithFocus.MoveFocus(request);
    }
}
```

This works well, but I now need to detect a double click event on the rows of the DataGrid. I do this by adding InputBindings to the DataGrid and passing the SelectedItem as a command parameter:

```
...
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding AnotherCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItem}" />
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
...
```

The problem is that double click is only detected on the RowDetails (which is good) but are not detected when double clicking the rows themselves (which is not).

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the source of the event is of type **DataGridDetailsPresenter**

```
private void SelectRowDetails(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Source is DataGridDetailsPresenter) // Like this
    {
        var row = sender as DataGridRow;
        if (row == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        row.Focusable = true;
        row.Focus();

        var elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
        if (elementWithFocus != null)
        {
            elementWithFocus.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: It should be `DataGridCellsPresenter` instead of `DataGridDetailsPresenter`